# Group by - Non-group-by expression in select clause

Tags: sql, excel, group-by, odbc

Sorry you will have to bear with me as i am relativly new to SQL. I am querying an ODBC in EXCEL. At the moment my dataset is massive so i am looking to narrow it down by grouping it by company name and date. not all my columns are calculated fields.I have put the Sum on the two i need adding up. When i try to return the data i get the error of Non-group-by expression in select clause

Please can someone help me out.

```
SELECT 

  SopOrder_0.SooOrderNumber
, Company_0.CoaCompanyName
, InvoiceCreditItem_0.InvoiceCreditItemID
, InvoiceCreditItem_0.IciInvoiceApproved
, InvoiceCreditItem_0.InvoiceCreditID
, InvoiceCreditItem_0.CompanySiteID
, InvoiceCreditItem_0.VatID
, InvoiceCreditItem_0.NominalID
, InvoiceCreditItem_0.IciCreatedDate
, Sum(InvoiceCreditItem_0.IciTotalNettValue)
, Sum(InvoiceCreditItem_0.IciVatValue)

FROM

SBS.PUB.Company Company_0
, SBS.PUB.Customer Customer_0
, SBS.PUB.InvoiceCreditItem InvoiceCreditItem_0
, SBS.PUB.SopOrder SopOrder_0

WHERE 

SopOrder_0.SopOrderID = InvoiceCreditItem_0.SopOrderID 
AND InvoiceCreditItem_0.CompanyID = Customer_0.CompanyID 
AND InvoiceCreditItem_0.CompanyID = Company_0.CompanyID
AND (Company_0.CoaCompanyName<>'ATOS')
AND InvoiceCreditItem_0.IciCreatedDate >= ?

GROUP BY 

Company_0.CoaCompanyName, InvoiceCreditItem_0.IciCreatedDate
```

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Jarlh thank you very much

Comment: Gordon try a nicer approach as mentioned im new to this your comment comes across like your treating me as an idiot